# Can't get specified value from JSON in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift3

a quick explanation for what I'm doing, there is a login screen user types an email, then there is a verification viewController pops up, the backend sends a verification code to the user's email, if the user's email + the verification code matches then he is logged in successfully and the backend respond with user's full info + unique ID. **So I want to get that unique ID alone.**

My Verification viewController code:

```
@IBAction func doneBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://anydomain.com/verif.php")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "bdemail=\(bdEmail)&verifcode=\(verifyCodeTxtField.text!)"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }else {
            do {
                if let data = data,
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
                    let users = json["BD_Id"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    print(users)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }

    task.resume()

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueIdentifier", sender: nil)

}
```

**But I only get the full response, I want the to get the Unique ID --> "BD_Id" alone so I can store it to use it in my app.**

Here is the response:

```
    { URL: http://anydomain.com/verif.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Tue, 07 Feb 2017 07:40:00 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} })


responseString = Optional(  [{"Rcode":101,"BD_Id":"8","BD_Name":"","BD_Email":"email@domain.com","BD_Country":"","BD_Home_Lat":"","BD_Home_Lon":"","BD_BT":"","BD_RH":"","BD_DOB":"0000-00-00","BD_Mobile":"","BD_Last_Donation":"0000-00-00","BD_Token":""}])
```

**The ID did't print out, so what is my mistake ?**

Thanks in advance. And please note that i'm very beginner in Swift Networking and thats my first time to deal with JSON.

UPDATE 1:

I have tried the following code but still didn't work, and the print statement didn't come out, that means that the data is empty||nil, but if that so how the last print statement prints the whole JSON script !

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }else {
            do {
                if data != nil {
                    print("Hello from the inside...")
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [[String: Any]]
                    for obj in json! {
                        if let bdId = obj["BD_Id"] as? String {
                            print(bdId)
                        } 
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
            }
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
```

Comment: You put three "let" tests into one line/condition. Break them to understand which test it didn't pass. Your JSON is a Array at top level, containing one object a Dictionary. So `json` should be as `[[String:Any]]`. Then from it, it your ID should be `json[0]["BD_Id"]`

Comment: Not related but in Swift 3 replace the `request` line with `var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://anydomain.com/verif.php")!)` and delete the `as URLRequest` cast. And both encodings can be reduced to `.utf8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ... your JSON is Array of Dictionaries .. `[[String:Any]]`

```
  do{
         let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as! [[String:Any]]
          for obj in json {
               if let bdId = obj["BD_Id"] as? String {
                   print(bdId)
               } 
          }
  }
  catch {
      print("Error with Json: \(error)")
  }
```